# Where can I find JARS for Oracle Agile PLM

Tags: java, oracle-agile-plm

I want to download files under attachments section of a part.
Where can I find the jars to write the code?

Which jar has AgileSessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

The jars are AgileAPI.jar and pxapi.jar. You can find them under the agile_home/integration/sdk/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

The jars are included in the SDK sample in [Oracle's Agile PLM Sample Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/agile-2684218.html) section.